# Characteristic function of dyadic rational numbers integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let us define $f(x) = 1$ if $x = k/2^n$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}, n \in \mathbb{N}$, and $f(x) = 0$ otherwise.

The first question asks, "at which points is its oscillation $\geq \kappa$? The second question asks, "Is it integrable? Explain, both by the Riemann-Lebesgue Theorem and directly from the definition."

I'm not quite understanding what the first question is asking. What does "oscillation $\geq \kappa$" mean exactly? Is it exactly the points $x$ where $x = k/2^n$ for $k \in \mathbb{Z}, n \in \mathbb{N}$?

Furthermore, since there are countable many of these $x$ (as $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{N}$ is countable), does it follow that you can cover them with a countable number of open intervals, (i.e. the set of all these $x$ is a zero set, and by Riemann-Lebesgue, it is integrable?)

Thanks.

Comment: By Lebesgue theorem, a bounded function $f$ on a segment is a Riemann integrable iff the set of the discontinuity points of $f$  has the Lebesgue measure 0. Since the function $f$ is discontinuous at each point, $f$ is not integrable on each segment of non-zero length.

Comment: Why is $f$ discontinuous at each point? Isn't it only discontinuous at the points $x$ where $x = k/2^n$ for $k \in \mathbb{Z}, n \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Since both the set of dyadic rationals and its complement are dense in $\mathbb R$, for each point $x\in\mathbb R$ and arbitrary small neighborhood $Ox\ni x$ we have $f(Ox)=\{0,1\}$, so $f$ is not continuous at the point $x$.